# Implicit Components: Set initial param values

Tags: python, openmdao

Using **OpenMDAO v1.7.3 Alpha**

I have a simple example OpenMDAO Problem consisting of 2 Implicit Components:

1. The first Component uses temperature to calculate voltage
2. and the second Component uses voltage to calculate temperature

(code at bottom of question)

Unfortunately, it's failing to converge when I run it in OpenMDAO. I think the problem is that I am not setting initial parameter values. as OpenMDAO is printing the following message to output:

> The following params are connected to unknowns that are updated out of order, so their initial values may contain uninitialized unknown values: ['battery_temp_comp.volt']

I have been scouring the [documentation](https://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/) but cannot figure out how to set this type of Problem (with Implicit Components) up properly. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

---

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import math as m
import numpy

from openmdao.api import Component, Group, Problem, Newton, ScipyGMRES


class BatteryVoltImplicitComp(Component):
    """ A Simple Implicit Component modelling a Battery's Voltage"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(BatteryVoltImplicitComp, self).__init__()

        # Params
        self.add_param('temp', 30.0)

        # Unknowns
        self.add_output('volt', 12.0)

        # States
        self.add_state('delta', 0.0)

    def calc_voltage(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        temp = params['temp']
        voltage_shift = (25.667 - temp) * 0.02933
        return 12.77 + voltage_shift

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        pass

    def apply_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        print("Params:   BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: {}".format(params['temp']))
        print("Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: {}".format(unknowns['volt']))
        print("Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.delta: {}".format(resids['delta']))
        calculated_voltage = self.calc_voltage(params, unknowns, resids)

        resids['delta'] = calculated_voltage - unknowns['volt']


class BatteryTempImplicitComp(Component):
    """ A Simple Implicit Component modelling a Battery's Temperature"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(BatteryTempImplicitComp, self).__init__()

        # Params
        self.add_param('volt', 12.0)
        # Unknowns
        self.add_output('temp', 30.0)

        # States
        self.add_state('delta', 0.0)

    def calc_temp(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        v = params['volt']
        room_temp = 23.0            # celsius
        batt_resist = 50e-3
        power = v**2 / batt_resist
        temp_increase = power / 50  # magic number
        return room_temp + temp_increase

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        pass

    def apply_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        print("Params:   BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: {}".format(params['volt']))
        print("Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: {}".format(unknowns['temp']))
        print("Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.delta: {}".format(resids['delta']))
        calculated_temp = self.calc_temp(params, unknowns, resids)

        resids['delta'] = calculated_temp - unknowns['temp']


if __name__ == '__main__':

    top = Problem()
    root = top.root = Group()

    root.add('battery_temp_comp', BatteryTempImplicitComp())
    root.add('battery_volt_comp', BatteryVoltImplicitComp())

    root.connect('battery_volt_comp.volt', 'battery_temp_comp.volt')
    root.connect('battery_temp_comp.temp', 'battery_volt_comp.temp')
    root.battery_temp_comp.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
    root.battery_temp_comp.deriv_options['form'] = 'central'
    root.battery_temp_comp.deriv_options['step_size'] = 1.0e-1
    root.battery_volt_comp.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
    root.battery_volt_comp.deriv_options['form'] = 'central'
    root.battery_volt_comp.deriv_options['step_size'] = 1.0e-1

    root.nl_solver = Newton()
    root.ln_solver = ScipyGMRES()

    top.setup()
    top.run()

    print('Solution (battery_volt_comp): volt = {}, temp = {}, resid = {}'.format(top['battery_volt_comp.volt'], top['battery_volt_comp.temp'], top['battery_volt_comp.delta']))
    print('Solution (battery_temp_comp): volt = {}, temp = {}, resid = {}'.format(top['battery_temp_comp.volt'], top['battery_temp_comp.temp'], top['battery_temp_comp.delta']))
```

---

Output:

> ########################################
>
> Setup: Checking root problem for potential issues...
>
> No recorders have been specified, so no data will be saved. Group ''
>   has the following cycles: [['battery_temp_comp', 'battery_volt_comp']]
>
> The following params are connected to unknowns that are updated out of
>   order, so their initial values may contain uninitialized unknown
>   values: ['battery_temp_comp.volt']
>
> Setup: Check of root problem complete.
>
> ########################################
>
> Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 30.0
>   Resids:  BatteryTempImplicitComp.delta: 0.0
>   Params:  BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 30.0
>   Unknowns:  BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Resids:  BatteryVoltImplicitComp.delta: 0.0
>   Params:  BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 12.1
>   Unknowns:  BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 30.0
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.delta: 50.6
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.9
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 30.0
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.delta: 50.6
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 30.0
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.delta: 50.6
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 30.0
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.delta: 50.6
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 30.1
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.delta: 0.64291311
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 29.9
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.delta: 0.64291311

...

> Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: nan
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: nan
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.delta: 0.64291311
>   [root] NL: NEWTON 1 | FAILED to converge after 1 iterations
>   Solution (battery_volt_comp): volt = nan, temp = nan, resid = -inf
>   Solution (battery_temp_comp): volt = nan, temp = nan, resid = -inf

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Instead of

```
# Params
self.add_param('temp', 30.0)
# Unknowns
self.add_output('volt', 12.0)
# States
self.add_state('delta', 0.0)
...
resids['delta'] = calculated_temp - unknowns['temp']
```

I needed to do this:

```
# Params
self.add_param('temp', 30.0)
# Unknowns / Residuals
self.add_state('volt', 12.0)
...
resids['volt'] = calculated_voltage - unknowns['volt']
```

---

> Unfortunately, it's failing to converge when I run it in OpenMDAO. I think the problem is that I am not setting initial parameter values.

While initial parameter values were not the cause of my problem, the easiest way to set initial values is:

```
top.setup()
top['battery_temp_comp.temp'] = 23.0
top.run()
```

---

Order of 1st execution is determined by order of `connect` statements. `Group.list_order()` will print out the execution order of Components within a group.

---

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from openmdao.api import Component, Group, Problem, Newton, ScipyGMRES


class BatteryVoltImplicitComp(Component):
    """ A Simple Implicit Component modeling a Battery's Voltage"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(BatteryVoltImplicitComp, self).__init__()

        # Params
        self.add_param('temp', 30.0)

        # Unknowns / Residuals
        self.add_state('volt', 12.0)

    def calc_voltage(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        temp = params['temp']
        voltage_shift = (25.667 - temp) * 0.02933
        return 12.77 + voltage_shift

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        pass

    def apply_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        print("Params:   BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: {}".format(params['temp']))
        print("Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: {}".format(unknowns['volt']))
        print("Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: {}".format(resids['volt']))
        calculated_voltage = self.calc_voltage(params, unknowns, resids)

        resids['volt'] = calculated_voltage - unknowns['volt']


class BatteryTempImplicitComp(Component):
    """ A Simple Implicit Component modeling a Battery's Temperature"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(BatteryTempImplicitComp, self).__init__()

        # Params
        self.add_param('volt', 12.0)

        # Unknowns / Residuals
        self.add_state('temp', 30.0)

    def calc_temp(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        v = params['volt']
        room_temp = 23.0            # celsius
        batt_resist = 50e-3
        power = v**2 / batt_resist
        temp_increase = power / 50  # magic number
        return room_temp + temp_increase

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        pass

    def apply_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        print("Params:   BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: {}".format(params['volt']))
        print("Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: {}".format(unknowns['temp']))
        print("Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: {}".format(resids['temp']))
        calculated_temp = self.calc_temp(params, unknowns, resids)

        resids['temp'] = calculated_temp - unknowns['temp']


if __name__ == '__main__':

    top = Problem()
    root = top.root = Group()

    root.add('battery_volt_comp', BatteryVoltImplicitComp())
    root.add('battery_temp_comp', BatteryTempImplicitComp())

    root.connect('battery_volt_comp.volt', 'battery_temp_comp.volt')
    root.connect('battery_temp_comp.temp', 'battery_volt_comp.temp')
    root.battery_temp_comp.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
    root.battery_temp_comp.deriv_options['form'] = 'central'
    root.battery_temp_comp.deriv_options['step_size'] = 1.0e-4
    root.battery_volt_comp.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'
    root.battery_volt_comp.deriv_options['form'] = 'central'
    root.battery_volt_comp.deriv_options['step_size'] = 1.0e-4

    root.nl_solver = Newton()
    root.ln_solver = ScipyGMRES()
    top.setup()
    top['battery_temp_comp.temp'] = 23.0
    top.run()

    print('Solution (battery_volt_comp): volt = {}, temp = {}'.format(top['battery_volt_comp.volt'], top['battery_volt_comp.temp']))
    print('Solution (battery_temp_comp): volt = {}, temp = {}'.format(top['battery_temp_comp.volt'], top['battery_temp_comp.temp']))
```

Output:

> ########################################
>
> Setup: Checking root problem for potential issues...
>
> No recorders have been specified, so no data will be saved. Group ''
>   has the following cycles: [['battery_temp_comp', 'battery_volt_comp']]
>
> The following params are connected to unknowns that are updated out of order, 
>   so their initial values may contain uninitialized unknown values:
>   ['battery_temp_comp.volt']
>
> Setup: Check of root problem complete.
>
> ########################################
>
> Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 100.0
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 0.0
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 100.0
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 0.0
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 100.0001
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: -1.41018689
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 99.9999
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: -1.41018689
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 100.0
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 12.0001
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: -1.41018689
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 100.0
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.9999
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: -1.41018689
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 12.0001
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 100.0
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: -19.4
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.9999
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 100.0
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: -19.4
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 100.0001
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: -19.4
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 12.0
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 99.9999
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: -19.4
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3436283598
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.2988322548
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: -19.4
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.2988322548
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3436283598
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: -1.41018689
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.2989322548
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3436283598
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 1.77166725734e-10
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.2987322548
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3436283598
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 1.77166725734e-10
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.2988322548
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3437283598
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 1.77166725734e-10
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.2988322548
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3435283598
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 1.77166725734e-10
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3437283598
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.2988322548
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 0.172329491217
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3435283598
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.2988322548
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 0.172329491217
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3436283598
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.2989322548
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 0.172329491217
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3436283598
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.2987322548
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 0.172329491217
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3396364502
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.4349355547
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 0.172329491217
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.4349355547
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3396364502
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 1.77166725734e-10
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.4350355547
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3396364502
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 2.87769807983e-13
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.4348355547
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3396364502
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 2.87769807983e-13
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.4349355547
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3397364502
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 2.87769807983e-13
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.4349355547
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3395364502
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 2.87769807983e-13
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3397364502
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.4349355547
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 6.37414106563e-06
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3395364502
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.4349355547
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 6.37414106563e-06
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3396364502
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.4350355547
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 6.37414106563e-06
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3396364502
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.4348355547
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 6.37414106563e-06
>   Params: BatteryTempImplicitComp.volt: 11.3396363025
>   Unknowns: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 74.4349405893
>   Resids: BatteryTempImplicitComp.temp: 6.37414106563e-06
>   Params: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.temp: 74.4349405893
>   Unknowns: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 11.3396363025
>   Resids: BatteryVoltImplicitComp.volt: 2.87769807983e-13
>   Solution (battery_volt_comp): volt = 11.3396363025, temp = 74.4349405893
>   Solution (battery_temp_comp): volt = 11.3396363025, temp = 74.4349405893